# Customize marker in angular-leaflet-directive with circleMarker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, marker, angular-leaflet-directive

I'm wondering if anyone has had experience modifying `angular-leaflet-directive` to support the creation of `circleMarkers` rather than sourcing an `img`.

Currently, you can create markers that will be populated on the Leaflet map by listing them as JSON in the following manner:

```
trip.end.marker = {
    main: {
        lat: trip.end.loc.lat,
        lng: trip.end.loc.lng,
        icon: {
          iconUrl: 'img/leaf-orange.png',
          shadowUrl: 'img/leaf-shadow.png',
          iconSize:     [38, 95],
          shadowSize:   [50, 64],
          iconAnchor:   [22, 94],
          shadowAnchor: [4, 62]
        } 
    }
};
```

I'm wondering if `icon` can easily be modified to also allow for the description of a `circleMarker` instead of an icon?